# Stretch to MinMax results in blank render output in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, multi-band, post-processing

I am a new QGIS user, and I can't figure out if I encountered a bug. 
If I have a multi-layer image, and "Multiband color" -> "Stretch to MinMax" selected I get the following behaviour. QGIS takes a bit of time to render and the output is blank. I need to force refresh of the view-port, and out of 5 renders randomly 1 time it renders correctly.

If I select "Stretch and clip to MinMax" then everything is fine, except I get clipping.

[image]

Blank View-port looks as follows: 
[image]

Comment: Does nobody know the answer to this problem? Did i discover something new?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if the issue is still there could you offer some test imagery?